# Не распознается и не импортируется HashMap

Tags: java, eclipse, java-hashmap, hashmap

Проблема:

При импорте HashMap, Eclipse выдает такую ошибку,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также не распознается сам метод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

структура файлов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что ваш класс тоже называется HashMap. В ошибке об этом прямым текстом написано.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже говорил ранее [Sergey Gornostaev](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204271/sergey-gornostaev), вы назвали свой класс также как и метод, переименуйте данный класс.